# Conversion from decimal to negabinary and vice versa in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, numbers, radix

Recently I set about to writing conversion functions in Haskell between decimal and [negabinary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negabinary). I tried to write them in as much functional a style as possible, also aiming at brevity. In the answer below I present my take at the task. I'd be interested in your refinements of the method I employ or any comments whatsoever.

Comment: Might be better on the Code Review Stack Exchange?

Comment: Belongs on codereview.stackexchange

Comment: No, he really did ask a question, he just didn't phrase it like one. The question is, how do I count in negabinary in Haskell? He could also have put the solution on RosettaCode, but the question part is real. I literally had the question and this was the best search result and answers that question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my effort:

```
type NegaBinary = [Int]

toInt :: NegaBinary -> Int
toInt = foldl' (\ y x -> x + y*(-2)) 0

fromInt :: Int -> NegaBinary
fromInt = reverse . unfoldr (\ x -> if x == 0 then Nothing else Just (let (d,m) = x `divMod` (-2) in (m,d)))
```

It's a shame that `divMod` returns the answers the wrong way around; otherwise this would be a bit shorter still.

Comment: Well, I tested your functions and while `toInt` works fine, `fromInt` returns the wrong result - also, you have `-1`s among your digits. Here's the edited output: `fromInt 15 => [-1,-1,0,0,0,-1]` and `toInt [1,0,0,1,1] => 15`

Comment: You're right. Perhaps there's some way to tweak this to fix the result...

Comment: Perhaps the fix is the *ugly* modification to `rem` and `div` that I had to make ;)

Answer (score 0):

Below are my two functions for converting back and forth:

```
type NegaBinary = String

dec2negbin :: Int -> NegaBinary
dec2negbin = reverse .
             map intToDigit .
                 unfoldr (\x -> if x==0 then Nothing else Just(abs(xrem x (-2)), xdiv x (-2)))
    where
      xrem a b = if b > 0 then rem a b else (-(rem a (-b)))
      xdiv a b = if b > 0 then div a b else (-(div a (-b)))

negbin2dec :: NegaBinary -> Int
negbin2dec = sum . map (\x -> (snd x)*(-2)^(fst x)) . zip [0..] . reverse . map digitToInt
```

I defined the `NegaBinary` type just for clarity. The `dec2negbin` employs the `unfoldr` function for sequential divisions and remainder calculations. I also used two local functions: `xrem` and `xdiv`, because the standard functions (`rem` and `div`) had the undesirable behavior of always approaching the dividend from below (meaning that in `div a b => c` `b*c` is always lower than `a`). What I wanted is for it to approach in the direction *from* zero, so the behavior is different for positive and negative dividends. I know the definition of `dec2negbin` is a bit bulky, so improvements are welcome.